# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

Here is my sample data

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider-date').noUiSlider({
        behaviour: 'drag',
        connect: true,
        range: {
        'min':  timestamp('2015-03-08 11:52:30'),
        'max':  timestamp('2015-03-09 11:52:02')
        },
        // Steps of one week
        step: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,

        // Two more timestamps indicate the handle starting positions.
        start: [ timestamp('2015-03-08 11:52:30'), timestamp('2015-03-09 13:29:34') ],

        // No decimals
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        })
    });

    $("#slider-date").Link('lower').to($("#event-start"), setDate);
    $("#slider-date").Link('upper').to($("#event-end"), setDate);

    // Create a new date from a string, return as a timestamp.
    function timestamp(str){
        return new Date(str).getTime();
    }

    // Create a list of day and monthnames.
    var
        weekdays = [
            "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        ],
        months = [
            "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July",
            "August", "September", "October",
            "November", "December"
        ];

    // Append a suffix to dates.
    // Example: 23 => 23rd, 1 => 1st.
    function nth (d) {
      if(d>3 && d<21) return 'th';
      switch (d % 10) {
            case 1:  return "st";
            case 2:  return "nd";
            case 3:  return "rd";
            default: return "th";
        }
    }

    // Create a string representation of the date.
    function formatDate ( date ) {
        console.log(date.getDate());
        return weekdays[date.getDay()] + ", " +
            date.getDate() + nth(date.getDate()) + " " +
            months[date.getMonth()] + " " +
            date.getFullYear();
    }

    // Write a date as a pretty value.
    function setDate( value ){
        return $(this).html(formatDate(new Date(+value)));
    }

});
```

This is the plugin page and where I got the code structure from
http://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-dates

In the example they provided a year as the start/end min/max. I am providing a timestamp. May be the issue. Not sure.

Here is a screenshot of my console where the error is happening. It is performing the check on the `2015-03-08` date during the error, which is a Sunday which corresponds to `0`. Not sure what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what `$("#slider-date").Link('lower').to($("#event-start"), setDate)` does. But it might call `setDate` which will call `formatDate` before assigning the value to `weekdays`.

Comment: I'm with Oriol. Code is working if I strip it down. http://jsfiddle.net/08091hv8/

Comment: Wow, now I feel like a noob. It was because I put the Link code before the function that it calls. Not sure how to make a comment the answer.